# How to set auto size of textobject in SAP Crystal Report

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I am using SAP Crystal Reports in my Windows application (Visual Studio 2010) and I took a Box having a background color gray and a Text Object inside it. I took input from a user to insert a text. The user entered a very long length text, say about 5-6 lines. I enabled the `can grow` property on this text object but still the problem is not resolved.

How can I set auto size of the textobject in SAP Crystal Report?

Comment: What value you set for Can grow ?